# error in return false on keyup

Tags: jquery, html

Here is html

```
    <form name="passwordchng" method="post" action="">
       <input name="_curpasswd" id="curpasswd" size="20" autocomplete="off" type="password" />
       <input name="_newpasswd" id="newpasswd" size="20" autocomplete="off" type="password" />
       <input name="_confpasswd" id="confpasswd" size="20" autocomplete="off" type="password" />
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" />
    </form>
```

Here is jquery

```
  <script> 
    $("#newpasswd").keyup(function() {
        if($("#curpasswd").val()==$("#newpasswd").val()){
            $(".newpasserror").css({"color":"red","margin-left":"10px"}).text("No changes made to your password.");
            return false;
        }
        else{
          $(".newpasserror").css({"color":"red","margin-left":"10px"}).text("A strong Password should have at least 1 alphabet,1 digit and 1 special character."); 
          return true;
        }
    });
 </script>
```

It should not allow submitting form when if condition executes. Here form is submitting even both passwords are same...

Comment: try `keydown` in place of `keyup`

Comment: If you want to prevent the submission of the form you should listen to submit event not keyup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use validation on `submit` instead of `keyup` if you want to return true or false. LIke:

```
$("#passwordchng").submit(function() {

    if($("#curpasswd").val()==$("#newpasswd").val())
    {
        $(".newpasserror").css({"color":"red","margin-left":"10px"}).text("No changes made to your password.");
        return false;
    }

    else
    {
        $(".newpasserror").css({"color":"red","margin-left":"10px"}).text("A strong Password should have at least 1 alphabet,1 digit and 1 special character.");
        return true;
    }

 });
```

## [See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cL80n3nq/)

> Note: *Id* is given to form

Answer (score 0):

You can disable submit button in if condition using:

```
 $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

and enable again in else condition using:

```
 $('input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
```

**COMPLETE CODE:**

```
 $("#newpasswd").keyup(function() {
  if($("#curpasswd").val()==$("#newpasswd").val())
    {
    $(".newpasserror").css({"color":"red","margin-left":"10px"}).text("No changes made to your password.");
    $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
}
else
{
    $(".newpasserror").css({"color":"red","margin-left":"10px"}).text("A strong Password should have at least 1 alphabet,1 digit and 1 special character."); 
    $('input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this..**

```
<form name="passwordchng" method="post" action="">
  <input name="_curpasswd" id="curpasswd" size="20" autocomplete="off" type="password" />
   <input name="_newpasswd" id="newpasswd" size="20" autocomplete="off" type="password" onChange="password();"/>
    <input name="_confpasswd" id="confpasswd" size="20" autocomplete="off" type="password" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" />
    <div id="message"></div>
   </form>
<script>
function password() {

    var curpasswd = $("#curpasswd").val();
    var newpasswd = $("#newpasswd").val();

    if (curpasswd != newpasswd)
        $("#message").html("Passwords do not match!");
    else
        $("#message").html("Passwords match.");
}

$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#newpasswd").keyup(password);
});

</script>
```